# react empty classlist attribute?

Tags: reactjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I'm new to react :)

If my component render looks like this:

```
render() {
return (
  <object-search className="m-t-xs">
    <div className="stats-title pull-left">
      <h4>Object Search</h4>
```

and my tests are:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    component = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(<ObjectSearch {...props}/>);
    renderedDOM = () => ReactDOM.findDOMNode(component);
});
it('should render with the correct DOM', () => {
    const parent = renderedDOM();
    expect(parent.tagName).toBe('OBJECT-SEARCH');
    expect(parent.children.length).toBe(7);
    expect(parent.classList[0]).toEqual('m-t-xs');
})
```

why am I seeing an empty classList attribute?

```
Home page ObjectSearch Rendering of ObjectSearch on componentDidMount should render with the correct DOM FAILED
Expected '' to equal 'm-t-xs'.
```

Note: using the karma test runner and jasmine

Comment: Is `object-search` a valid HTML DOM name? Never heard that one.

Comment: Argh! I've been pulling my hair out over this for hours! Thank you @NiyokoYuliawan!

Comment: Any idea why it expects: Expected 'DIV' to equal 'div' for <div className="m-t-xs">?

Comment: `tagName` property will return uppercase. So you should change `. toBe('div')` into `.toBe('DIV')`

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName ah ha! Thanks for your help @NiyokoYuliawan :)